# How to handle 800k points as MVT

Tags: leaflet, postgis, vector-tiles

I have a table with about 800k points with information that includes bathimetry stored on PostGIS and served using ST_AsMVTGeom this is connected to a Web App develop using Leaflet but a certain levels (0-5) a single Vector-tile it's contaning all the data which makes the Query very slow (it takes minutes). I wonder if there exists (whitin PostGIS) a way to simplify the rows output depending on zoom level.

I'm using the following Query to create the tiles:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(q.*, 'bathymetry_layer', 4096, 'geom')
    FROM (
      SELECT
          c.gid AS id,
          c.x,
          c.y,
          c.z,
          c.name,
          c.inst,
          ST_AsMVTGeom(
              geom,
              ST_MakeEnvelope(-86.8798828125, 20.632784250388028, -86.8359375, 20.673905264672843, 4326),
              4096,
              256,
              false
          ) geom
      FROM bathymetry_table WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(-86.8798828125, 20.632784250388028, -86.8359375, 20.673905264672843, 4326) AND ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(-86.8798828125, 20.632784250388028, -86.8359375, 20.673905264672843, 4326))
    ) q
```

Result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Index Scan using geodat_batimetria_catoche_xcalak_geom_idx on geodat_batimetria_catoche_xcalak c  (cost=0.29..8.56 rows=1 width=101) (actual time=0.117..11539.038 rows=434271 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000002B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA23440'::geometry) AND (geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000002B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA23440'::geometry))
  Filter: _st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000002B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0D34D621058493540492EFF21FD9E55C0516B9A779CA234402B8716D9CECB55C0516B9A779CA23440'::geometry)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 5
Planning time: 7.222 ms
Execution time: 11579.044 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This function would generate vector tiles for all zooms, clustering points together for low zooms (0-10), and keeping them as is for zooms 11+.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tile(z integer, x integer, y integer) RETURNS bytea AS
$$
    -- MVTs can be combined by concatenating them together.
SELECT STRING_AGG(mvt, '') AS mvt
FROM (
         -- Each `mvt` must be non-NULL, otherwise UNION ALL will skip them all
         -- First generate the tile for the zoomed-out layer, clustering points together
         SELECT COALESCE(ST_AsMVT(tile, 'bathymetry_layer', 4096, 'geom'), '') AS mvt
         FROM (
                  -- Create a cluster of points for each tile
                  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(center, 3857),
                                      ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y),
                                      extent => 4096)
                             AS geom
                         -- need to add all the other columns here,
                         -- but they either have to be aggregated for each cluster,
                         -- or you need to pick one point to represent the whole cluster
                  FROM (
                           -- Cluster points into groups using DBSCAN algorithm
                           SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS center
                           FROM (SELECT *,
                                        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 3857),
                                            -- Decide how many clusters you want per tile.
                                            -- at zoom 0, earth circumference equals 1 tile. At each subsequent zoom level,
                                            -- there are twice as many tiles for the same circumference.
                                            -- Additionally, break each tile into 256 clusters
                                        (40075016.6855785 / (256 * 2 ^ z)),
                                        1) OVER () AS cluster_id
                                 FROM bathymetry_table
                                      -- This assumes your data should be clustered before zoom 11, and shouldn't after. 
                                      -- Keep this value in sync with the one below
                                 WHERE z < 11
                                   -- This assumes your data is in 4326. The envelope is always generated in 3857.
                                   AND geom && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y), 4326))
                                    AS cluster
                           group by cluster_id) AS clusters) as tile

         UNION ALL

         SELECT COALESCE(ST_AsMVT(tile, 'bathymetry_layer', 4096, 'geom', 'id'), '') AS mvt
         FROM (
                  -- Once zoomed in, there is no longer a need to cluster points
                  -- Note that the list of columns is different from the one above - you many want to adjust that.
                  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(coord, 3857),
                                      ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y),
                                      extent => 4096)
                               AS geom
                       , c.gid AS id
                       , c.x
                       , c.y
                       , c.z
                       , c.name
                       , c.inst
                  FROM bathymetry_table c
                  WHERE z >= 11
                    AND c.geom && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y), 4326)) as tile) AS mvt
    ;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
                STRICT
                PARALLEL SAFE;
```